# Reduce number of functions that append to lists

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a working code, but would like to reduce my number of functions. Now i use 4 functions as seen in the code below. I cant use "return" to return a lsit, since Im calling the functions with a PyQt5 signal.  If i do this i do not get the list returned.

Is it possible to populate self.list1 and self.list2 with the same function?

```
self.list1 = []
self.list2 = []

self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect_to_Folder1)
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect_to_Folder2)

def copy_text1(self):
    text = user_input
    self.list1.append(text)

def connect_to_Folder1(self):
    if connected:
        copy_text1()
    else:
        connect_to_folder
        copy_text1()

def copy_text2(self):
    text = user_input
    self.list1.append(text)    

def connect_to_Folder2(self):
    if connected:
        copy_text2()
    else:
        connect_to_folder
        copy_text2()


use self.list1
use self.list2
```